# getUserMedia not working on new browsers

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am playing around with HTML Media Capture and the `getUserMedia` method. It is not working with Chrome and I get the alert included on failure.

Here is the sample code I used:

```js
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia(
        // constraints
        {
            video: true,
            audio: true
        },
        // successCallback
        function (localMediaStream) {
            var video = document.querySelector('video');
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
            // Do something with the video
            video.play();
        },
        // errorCallback
        function (err) {
            console.log("The following error occured: " + err);
        }
    );
} else {
    alert("getUserMedia not supported by your web browser or Operating system version");
}
```

Comment: For the correct HTML Media Capture syntax (there were several revisions) see https://addpipe.com/blog/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/

Comment: Use the latest version... navigator.getUserMedia() is now replaced by navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia https://webrtc.github.io/samples/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard navigator.getUserMedia is not recognized on Chrome. it works with Microsoft Edge. You will need to add vendor prefixes.
for Chrome: `navigator.webkitGetUserMedia`

Here is a working code on JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/RamiSarieddine/t9d3hpyr/

```js
//browser support check "ms" vendor function is for IE8
navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia       ||
                           navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                           navigator.mozGetUserMedia    ||
                           navigator.msGetUserMedia );

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia(
        // constraints
        {
            video: true,
            audio: true
        },
        // successCallback
        function (localMediaStream) {
            var video = document.querySelector('video');
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
            // Do something with the video
            video.play();
        },
        // errorCallback
        function (err) {
            console.log("The following error occured: " + err);
        }
    );
} else {
    alert("getUserMedia not supported by your web browser or Operating system version");
}
```

Comment: FIREFOX is now the issue as you get this on your fiddle and all my apps LOL "navigator.mozGetUserMedia has been replaced by navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia The following error occured: NotReadableError: Failed to allocate videosource"

Comment: @Rami Sarieddine This above URL in firefox not working pls check .

Answer (score 3):

`navigator.getUserMedia` has been superseded by [`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia).

The latter uses modern promises and is available natively in Edge, Firefox, and Chrome. There is also [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter), the official WebRTC polyfill that helps them catch up to the standard (e.g. `srcObject`).

Here is a fiddle that works in all three: https://jsfiddle.net/srn9db4h/

```
var constraints = { video: true, audio: true };

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then(stream => video.srcObject = stream)
  .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Comment: that fiddle is broken on both Chrome and FF using latest versions of both ... NotFoundError: The object can not be found here.

Comment: @ScottStensland That error usually means no cameras or microphones were found on your system. Fiddle still works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

> It is not working with Chrome

Try using `webkit` , `moz` prefixes , see [Navigator.getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia#Examples)

```js
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia; 
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this little validation?

```
async getMediaStream(constraints): Promise<MediaStream> {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices
      && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then((stream) => resolve(stream))
        .catch(err => reject(err));
    } else {
      const getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia
      || navigator['webkitGetUserMedia']
      || navigator['mozGetUserMedia']
      || navigator['msGetUserMedia'];
      getUserMedia(
        constraints,
        (stream) => resolve(stream),
        (err) => reject(err)
      );
    }
  });
}

const isEdge = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Edge') !== -1
  && (!!navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob || !!navigator.msSaveBlob);

getMediaStream({
  audio: isEdge ? true : {
    echoCancellation: false
  }
})
.then(stream => console.log(stream))
.catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Regards, Nicholls :)