# navigator.mozGetUserMedia has been replaced by navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, barcode

I have error on barcode scanner plugin. It's working in chrome but not working in Firefox. I am getting error in console :

> navigator.mozGetUserMedia has been replaced by
>   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia

My demo url: https://rawgit.com/saravanasksp/myproject/master/src/index.html

Anyone please let me know about the issue.

Comment: it's because `navigator.mozGetUserMedia` has been replaced by `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` - check [dicumentation for mediaDevices.getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) - oh, and by the way, that's **not an error** it's a warning, so it won't break your code ... *yet*

Comment: @JaromandaX how to resolve this issue. can you add some code to brief. I changed the code as per documentation but still same error in firefox.

Comment: Note that there is no certainty that bugs fixed in `mediaDevices` API are ever applied to the old version, so it may actually already break your code. If you need to support old versions, use [the official shim](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getUserMedia not working on new browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985806/getusermedia-not-working-on-new-browsers) even though the accepted answer is wrong... [Check the one by @jib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34034763/3702797) (MediaStream implementor for FF)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just change your function call. The constraint objects passed to each are the same the main difference is the navigator.mozGetUserMedia relies on callbacks. The new navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia returns a Promise.

So where you had

```
navigator.mozGetUserMedia(constraints, 
   stream => handleStream(stream), 
    err => handleError(err));
```

You now have

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(stream => {handleStream(stream)})
.catch(err => {handleError(err)}
```

Sorry I should have added links

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/media-devices
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Comment: Lol just realised this is 3 years old. Hopefully someone else can use my answer ;)